# Generate separate cache for logged in user with COutputCache and CHttpCacheFilter in Yii

Tags: php, caching, yii

I am using this code

```
public function filters()
{
    return array(
                array(
                    'COutputCache + index',
                    'duration'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest ? 3600 : 0,
                    //'varyByParam'=>array(),
                ),
                array(
                    'CHttpCacheFilter + index',
                    'lastModified'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest?Yii::app()->db->createCommand("SELECT MAX(`f_modified`) FROM {{post}}")->queryScalar():date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                ),
    );
}
```

As you can see I have given duration and last modified in both depending on whether user is guest. Now when I logout my page is still showing that user is logged in.

Comment: This has nothing wrong, CHttpCacheFilter forces the cache headers on the browser. So you probably have to hit Control + R to get a fresh copy.

Comment: That does not make this caching useable.

Comment: Can you post the HTTP response header both when the user is logged in and when user has logged out?